# How to use touchscreen on startup with kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

At the moment I am building an application in kivy for my pi 3. It should support touchscreen, as I would like to use my newly bought eGalax Inc. USB TouchController for it. The application starts and works when I just try to run it from command.

However I wish to start it from boot, without user-interaction for starting it. Like from the rc.local script. I've tried some different things already, but although the application starts, the touchscreen won't respond to my input. I'll provide my `.kivy/config.ini` file:

```
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 1
log_level = info
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon = 
keyboard_mode = 
keyboard_layout = qwerty
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 1
pause_on_minimize = 0
kivy_clock = default
default_font = ['Roboto', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',     'data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf']
log_maxfiles = 100
window_shape = data/images/defaultshape.png
config_version = 20

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 'auto'
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 0
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0

[input]
mouse = mouse
#%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
egalax = hidinput,/dev/input/event0,rotation=90,invert_y=1
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]
cursor = 1
```

So if anybody got it working, what did you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a while I found a solution burried in this specific site.

If you've already set your .kivy/config.ini file up to work when you use a command to start kivy, this will work for you:

`"sudo cp ~/.kivy/config.ini /root/.kivy/config.ini"`

It copies the config file to the root folder, which made touchscreen on boot work for me.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542558/7757033)